# What property can I give superscript so that it doesn't influence/effect other text no matter where I move it?

Tags: html, css, text, format, superscript

I want to move the superscript numbers using CSS to have them float directly above the text instead of on the side, but I don't want it to create margins on the surrounding text.

I've tried using negative margins but it messed everything up if the superscripts aren't the same digits/size.

I want them to be flush like this: 70/80/90/100/110

Here's my HTML:

```
70/80<sup class="buffSup">-5</sup>/90<sup class="buffSup">-10</sup>/100<sup class="buffSup">-15</sup>/110<sup class="buffSup">-20</sup>
```

And here's as close as I got with the CSS:

```
.buffSup {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    color: green;
    font-weight:bold;
    left: -1.18em;
    top: -1.2em;
    font-size: 73%;
    margin-left: -0.45em;
    margin-right: -0.59em;
}
```

I'm also all ears for a better method to achieve this altogether but the content won't be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it as if the `sup` elements were never there, you need to take them out of the flow of the document. I've done this by using [`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).  (Here comes the magic part.) To then keep those elements positioned near the content, you make sure that their containing element (the `p`) also has a positioning context - `position: relative` in this case.

Here's the CSS:

```
p {
  position: relative;
}

sup {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em;
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 73%;
}
```

Note that I removed some stuff for simplicity, and just styled the `sup` elements directly, rather than using their class.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, I have a feeling this is going to be useful for more than just this instance.

Sorry about the hiccups, this was my first time here.

Comment: No prob. Welcome to the site - I think you're gonna do just fine here.  ;)

Comment: If I try to position them left or right they all collapse and stack on top of one another!  Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, adding a `left: 1em` rule will make them all move to that position, *relative to their parent* which is the paragraph. Try using `text-indent: -1em;` or something to move them around.